# How to know when the pushed view stopped moving. UIKit Dynamics

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit-dynamics

I have a `UIView` on which I apply a `UIPushBehavior` of mode `UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous`. What is the easiest way to know when the pushed `UIView` stops moving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view controller, set the delegate property of your UIDynamicAnimator to be self. Then you will receive dynamicAnimatorDidPause notifications when the animation stops. Define a dynamicAnimatorDidPause function to handle the event. See the Xcode documentation on UIDynamicAnimator.

Comment: It looks like this is the only option. Thanks.

Comment: It's not sp much "the only option" ... it's .... how you do it :)  How else did you think you could be notified, other than, a delegate?!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I receive the notification up to seconds after the animation stops - maybe because it keeps oscillating for a while with an imperceptibly tiny amplitude?

Comment: You are correct, bcattle. These dynamic animations sometimes take a long time to "stop" as iOS sees it. You can add more damping. Someone may know (but I don't) if there is a way to add some hysteresis to the animation, so you could tell it to stop at some threshold velocity. I guess you could set a timer and stop it after a time limit, but this is getting away from simple.